# Boxplots where date grouped by year

Tags: sas, boxplot

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216748/group-summary-statistics-by-year-based-on-a-date-field) about grouping in SAS. Drawing on that question, and using the same data set, I am struggling to make a box plot.

The data look like this:

```
Date    Close   Volume
12/31/2014  222.41  2402097
12/30/2014  222.23  2903242
12/29/2014  225.71  2811828
12/26/2014  227.82  3327016
12/24/2014  222.26  1333518
12/23/2014  220.97  4513321
12/22/2014  222.6   4806917
12/19/2014  219.29  6910461
12/18/2014  218.26  7483349
12/17/2014  205.82  7367834
12/16/2014  197.81  8426105
12/15/2014  204.04  5218252
12/12/2014  207 7173782
```

This data set actually covers two full years 2013 - 14. I would like a boxplot for each year and variable (Close and Volume).

Here is what I tried:

```
proc boxplot data=tsla;
class Date;
format Date year.;
   plot Close*Date;
run;
```

But that returns an error "

```
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
162  format Date year.;
163     plot Close*Date;
164  run;
```

"

What's the right order then?

How can I get SAS to give me 4 boxplots total? 2 variables (Close and Volume) and over two years (2013 - 14)?

Comment: I think you need a semicolon after the `skeletal` to end your `plot` statement.

Comment: Thanks, semi colon added but now getting an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `class` statement in `proc boxplot`.

First, add a "year" variable using a data step.

```
data tsla2;
  set tsla;
  year=year(date);
run;
```

Sort by year:

```
proc sort data=tsla2;
  by year;
run;
```

Use `by` statement in `proc boxplot`:

```
proc boxplot data=tsla2;
  by year;
  plot close*year;
  plot volume*year;
run;
```

If you want all the years plotted together for each variable, there is no need to sort or use a `by` statement. Just do:

```
proc boxplot data=tsla2;
  plot close*year;
  plot volume*year;
run;
```

Comment: When you say "add year=year(Date) to data step, what do you mean exactly? I used the import feature using the SAS gui to import the data. Is it possible to add this step in, something like this:
proc boxplot year=year(Date) data=tsla;
year=year(Date);
 plot Close*Date;
run;

Comment: This is great. I don't think I'd have been able to figure that out I was researching adding fields to SAS. Boxplots are now showing. Thanks again

Comment: You shouldn't need the data step.  The original code would work if the `class` statement was replaced with `by`.  The data would still need to be presorted by Date.

Comment: That's true, but it would produce a different result. I'm not quite clear on which method would be closer to the desired result.